# springboot security swagger springfox-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

**pom.xml**

```xml
<!-- swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**spring-security** configure

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        String[] SWAGGERS = {
                "/swagger/**",
                "/v3/**"
        };

        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry ->
                        expressionInterceptUrlRegistry
                                // 放行 druid 页面
                                .antMatchers("/zhy-druid/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers(SWAGGERS).anonymous()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        httpSecurity
                .formLogin(httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer
                                .loginPage("/authentication")
                                .successHandler(accountAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                                .failureHandler(accountAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                );

        httpSecurity
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer
                                .logoutUrl("/cancellation")
                                .logoutSuccessHandler(accountLogoutSuccessHandler)
                );

        httpSecurity
                .exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(accountAuthenticationEntryPointHandler)
                                .accessDeniedHandler(accountAccessDeniedHandler)
                );

        httpSecurity
                .cors();

        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
```

**application-local.yml**

```yaml
springfox:
  documentation:
    enabled: true
    swagger-ui:
      base-url: /swagger
```

I get this result.

Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid `Swagger` or `OpenAPI` version field. Supported version fields are swagger: 2.0 and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

`Openapi` is the latest library and recommended for spring boot applications. It's the next version of swagger.

Add the below code for work `openapi` in your application.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

**Spring-Security** configure to allow open api url.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/v3/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api-docs.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui.path: /api-docs.html
```

Comment: I found the reason, because gson caused the serialization problem, which has been solved. And I've replaced swagger with springdoc. Thank you for your advice.