# Swagger generated file uses mysterious import

Tags: java, maven, swagger, springfox

I just generated code using Swagger.io with the OpenApi 3.0 spec. The code it produces doesn't compile. Once class has this seemingly crucial import:

`import springfox.documentation.oas.annotations.EnableOpenApi;`

But I get this error: `package springfox.documentation.oas.annotations does not exist`

I can't figure out what I need to add to my pom.xml file to make the import work. The maven repo at https://mvnrepository.com/ doesn't let me search for a specific class, which makes no sense.

Comment: Usually one looks  for jar files on findjar.com  , and then when one found  on mvnrepository for proper maven coordinates.  Project istelf is here:   https://springfox.github.io/springfox/

Comment: Thank you. That helped with other missing classes, like io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI, but didn't help with springfox.documentation.oas.annotations.EnableOpenApi.

Comment: Well, look into project  on github.  There must be information somewhere  about distribution repository.    mvnrepository does not serach everywhere, and spring uses own repositories

Comment: Take a look at http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have missed `swagger oas` dependency so you are getting package not exist error. **Swagger oas** available in the below maven repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That helped with most of the problems with the package. I still can't build, because I'm getting an error on a call to a method called apiInfo(), with a signature that's presumably `public springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo apiInfo()`

Comment: @MiguelMunoz, Swagger is old version, you should use openapi. Follow this link to integrate swagger in your application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557795/springboot-security-swagger-springfox-boot-starter/65558262#65558262

Comment: When I last used openApi, I found some options that I wanted to use were missing. I also didn't like the quality of the code they generated, although I had (smaller) problems with Swagger's generated code.

Comment: Add this maven dependecies and try `<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Although following @Sathia s suggestion I still can't build using openapi-generator-maven-plugin because internally deprecated class RelativePathProvider (current: BasePathProvider) is used during code generation. How can I solve this?

Comment: @du-it, I didn't understand. Can you post your question separately with more detail?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550300/how-to-resolve-that-openapi-generator-maven-plugin-uses-deprecated-class

Comment: @du-it, solution added and voted for your question.