# How to resolve that openapi-generator-maven-plugin uses deprecated class?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I try to use openapi-generator-maven-plugin together with Spring Boot 2.4.3 to generate code by the specifications made in an openapi.yaml according to some examples on the internet whereby no example provided the complete dependencies necessary to include.
The plugin generates a class named `OpenAPIDocumentationConfig` which internally uses the imported class `springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider`.

AFAIK this class is deprecated in favour of class `DefaultPathProvider` but I can't find a repository with this new class.

Here's my POM:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <springdoc.version>1.5.5</springdoc.version>
    <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SpringBoot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OpenApi / Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <!--<language>java</language>-->
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                            <!--<output>${project.basedir}/generated-sources</output>-->
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

[image]

---

Using only the `springdoc-openapi-ui` dependency results in even more errors:
[image]

With this updated POM:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <springdoc.version>1.5.5</springdoc.version>
    <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
    <openapi-generator.version>3.0.0</openapi-generator.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SpringBoot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OpenApi / Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <!--<language>java</language>-->
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                            <!--<output>${project.basedir}/generated-sources</output>-->
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The openapi.yaml specifying the code to be generated:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Title
  description: "REST API Dokumentation xxx"
  version: ${artifactId}
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
  contact:
    name: API Support
    email: xxx.yyy@zzz.de
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
#externalDocs:
servers:
  - url: http://{domain}:{port}
    description: The local server
    variables:
      domain:
        default: localhost
        description: api domain
      port:
        enum:
          - '8081'
        default: '8081'
paths:
  /api/hello:
    get:
      summary: Says 'hello' to the user.
      description: A test endpoint.
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: name
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            description: The person's name to address to.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok
        '500':
          description: Server error
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not as you can see from my edited question. It still doesn't build.

Comment: post your updated `pom.xml` here.

Comment: Updated POM posted.

Comment: `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` plugin not required. I have updated my answer with `pom.xml`, here I have added a plugin for `lombok`. please check

Comment: What is the advantage of the lombok plugin over the dependency? :-) 
With your changes I can conduct the build but I can't see the code generated that is specified in openapi.yaml (see updated question).

Comment: Lombok plugin is required on deployment. openapi.yaml is not all required when you use springdoc. Delete that openapi.yaml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229746/discussion-between-du-it-and-sathia).

Answer (score 0):

we can use useLombok and template with lombok

```
<useLombok>true</useLombok>
<templateDirectory>path to template folder</templateDirectory>
```

https://github.com/deviantlycan/openapi-generator-templates/tree/master/generator-templates/JavaSpring/spring-boot-lombok-actuator

Answer (score -1):

In your pom file, you are included all different openapis like [springfox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/), [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started), [swaggerv3](https://swagger.io/specification/) but it shouldn't be. Use any one library.

My suggestion is to use [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started) which is required minimal configuration.

Remove all openapi dependencies in your `pom.xml`. Add the below dependencies alone in **pom.xml**.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <springdoc.version>1.5.5</springdoc.version>
    <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
    <openapi-generator.version>3.0.0</openapi-generator.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SpringBoot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OpenApi / Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.yml**

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui.path: /app-api-docs.html
```

**Access the spring doc here**

```
http://localhost:8080/app-api-docs.html
```